# Printing from web application using Zebra Technologies printers

Tags: javascript, printing

We want to provide print functionality in our web application (ASP.NET, C#) for printing labels on the client machine.

Currently we are using "Dymo Label Printers" they provide a nice JavaScript API. Our client want to use Zebra printers (due to various advantages over Dymo Label Printers) but I failed to find any JavaScript API for these printers.

I came to know that there is an ActiveX control but that is too much old and I could not find any updated ActiveX control or JavaScript API. Can you please share your experience of Zebra printers? or please let me know some useful API to work with Zebra Printers on client side.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to entirely follow the StackOverflow paradigm, but I'll give my two cents.  Zebra's newer printers offer websocket connectivity that allows server side web application control: http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/link-os.html.  Their ActiveX control is no longer supported, as you note.  There is a Java applet out there called jZebra that might help you out: https://code.google.com/p/jzebra/.  But, as far as I know, there is no reputable Zebra Javascript library.

Comment: @Abdul Did you you ever solve this issue?

Comment: @Malcr001 not yet, have you found any solution if yes then please share it here, Thanks

Comment: @abdul no I have not found a solution which is why I asked. The jzebra project was the closest however as I need it to work on touch devices java applets will not work.

Comment: Does this help? https://developer.zebra.com/community/technologies/printers/label-printers/blog/2015/03/31/printing-from-websites-part-2

Comment: @Malcr001 now we are able to print labels on Zebra Label printer by using a third party component http://www.neodynamic.com/products/printing/raw-data/aspnet-mvc/ Note: I am not affiliated with this company in any capacity however their component works perfectly for us so far. We have customized and make the printing process very cleaner, let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 5):

Zebra now (2018-19) offers [Browser Print SDK](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/link-os/browser-print.html), which has the ability to print using JavaScript. I have used it successfully with S4M printer, on a Windows machine. 
A rough description is that it consists of a client program that acts as an HTTP server, and a JavaScript library that can be used by other JavaScript client scripts to communicate with the above server (i think two HTTP ports are used), and via server, with the printer driver. I have used ZPL language to send direct commands to the printer, using the above library.

Answer (score 0):

Zebra has "SendfiletoPrinter" API - look in their developer portal under Data Services APIs.

Easy to use it for cloud based printing.

Comment: Please post detailed guide how to use with references.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31899646)